# Transformer model not performing well (PyTorch)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, text-classification, transformer-model

I'm running a training job for transformer model with a task of assessing users English Proficiency.

The dataset I have is text written by a student. When running training, train accuracy go up to 0.99 but val accuracy is stuck in ~0.5. I have three classes for the labels (0,1,2).
Do you see any issues in the model architecture or do you have any suggestions/tips to improve performance?

Here's the model architecture:

```
class Head(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.key = nn.Linear(config.n_embed, config.head_size, bias=False)
        self.query = nn.Linear(config.n_embed, config.head_size, bias=False)
        self.value = nn.Linear(config.n_embed, config.head_size, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        # B = batch size, T = sequence length, C = number of channels
        B, T, C = x.shape
        # compute queries, keys and values
        k = self.key(x) # (B, T, C)
        q = self.query(x) # (B, T, C)
        wei = q @ k.transpose(-2, -1) * C ** -0.5 # (B, T, C) @ (B, C, T) -- > (B, T, T)
        #wei = wei.masked_fill(self.trail[:T, :T] == 0, float("-inf"))
        wei = F.softmax(wei, dim=-1)
        v = self.value(x) # (B, T, C)
        out = wei @ v # (B, T, T) @ (B, T, C) -- > (B, T, C)
        return out


class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.heads = nn.ModuleList([Head(config) for _ in range(config.n_head)])
        self.proj = nn.Linear(config.n_embed, config.n_embed)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(config.dropout)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        out = torch.cat([h(x) for h in self.heads], dim=-1)
        out = self.dropout(self.proj(out))
        return out


class FeedFoward(nn.Module):
    """ a simple linear layer followed by a non-linearity """

    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(config.n_embed, 4 * config.n_embed),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(4 * config.n_embed, config.n_embed),
            nn.Dropout(config.dropout),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.net(x)


class Block(nn.Module):
    """ Transformer block: communication followed by computation """

    def __init__(self, config):
        # n_embed: embedding dimension, n_head: the number of heads we'd like
        super().__init__()
        self.sa = MultiHeadAttention(config)
        self.ffwd = FeedFoward(config)
        self.ln1 = nn.LayerNorm(config.n_embed)
        self.ln2 = nn.LayerNorm(config.n_embed)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x + self.sa(self.ln1(x))
        x = x + self.ffwd(self.ln2(x))
        return x

class Assessment(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, config, device):
        super().__init__()
        self.config = config
        self.device = device
        self.token_embedding_table = nn.Embedding(config.vocab_size, config.n_embed, padding_idx=0)
        self.position_embedding_table = nn.Embedding(config.block_size, config.n_embed, padding_idx=0)
        self.blocks = nn.Sequential(*[Block(config) for _ in range(config.n_layer)])
        self.ln_f = nn.LayerNorm(config.n_embed)
        self.lm_head = nn.Linear(config.n_embed, config.output_size)

        self.apply(self._init_weights)


    def _init_weights(self, module):
        if isinstance(module, nn.Linear):
            torch.nn.init.normal_(module.weight, mean=0.0, std=0.02)
            if module.bias is not None:
                torch.nn.init.zeros_(module.bias)
        elif isinstance(module, nn.Embedding):
            torch.nn.init.normal_(module.weight, mean=0.0, std=0.02)


    def forward(self, idx, targets=None):
        # idx: (B, T)
        # targets: (B, T)
        B, T = idx.shape
        
        tok_emb = self.token_embedding_table(idx) # (B, T, C)
        pos_emb = self.position_embedding_table(torch.arange(T, device=self.device)) # (T, C) 
    
        x = tok_emb + pos_emb # (B, T, C)
        x = self.blocks(x) # (B, T, C)
        x = self.ln_f(x) # (B, T, C)
        
        logits = self.lm_head(x) # (B, T, C)
        logits = logits[:, -1, :] # (B, C)

        if targets is None:
            loss = None
        else:
            loss = F.cross_entropy(logits, targets)

        return logits, loss
```

appreciate the help!

I tried different hyper params with no luck at all in improving val accuracy.